# Excel cannot understand the format of data written by java

Tags: java, excel, apache, csv

I am having 2 issues using the apache POI to write data from a csv into an excel file.
The data consists of dates, and numbers
The issues are:

```
1) The numbers are written as strings.
2) Excel cannot read the date format (this messes the graphs up)
```

The code (that I received help with previously):

```
    String name = "test";
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(name);
    if (sheet == null) {
        sheet = wb.createSheet(name);
    }

    int rowCount = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/tmp/" + name + ".csv"));
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] rowData = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
        for (int col = 0; col < rowData.length; col++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(rowCount);
            if (row == null)
                row = sheet.createRow(rowCount);
            Cell cell = row.getCell(col);
            if (cell == null) {
                cell = row.createCell(col);
            }
            cell.setCellValue(rowData[col]);
        }
        rowCount++;
    }

    wb.write(new FileOutputStream(excel));
}
```

1) I tried using `Double.parseDouble(rowData[col])` when entering the data into the excel file. but this gives an empty string error. I even set the cell format with `style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("#,##0.0000"));` but it still does not work

2) I tried using the date format  `cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));` but still the excel graphs can't read this format. (when I manually copy and paste from the csv file it works).

So basically, when copying data using the apache poi, none of the other data that relies on the copied cells is updated. 
for example if a cell has a value of the average of 100 cells, and I manually copy data into those cells, it updates automatically. But when it copies through java, the cells do not update.

Comment: You could give the CSV file the extension `.xls` which Excel will accept. Dirty maybe.

Comment: But im still copying from a csv into an excel file. The issue is that java writes out the values as a string into the excel file cell.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do something more.

```
try {
    double value = Double.parseDouble(rowData[col]);
    cell.setCellValue(value);
} catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
    String value = rowData[col];
    cell.setCellValue(value);
}
```

*(However you might not use Apache POI and straight copy the CSV file to a `.xls`, if
it is just a need for double-click reading by Excel.)*

Comment: Yes, thank you, this solves the first issue about the numbers. So it sees if there is an empty string, it will catch it and set it to a string format. If there is no missing string it will write the value as a double. Am I understanding it right?

Comment: Yes, if it can be parse as double _(decimal point needed)_ then it uses `Cell.setCellValue(double)`.

Comment: Ahh.. excel still does not  update other cells with this new information. Like forexample there is a cell which displays the average for 10 cells. once the data is copied manually, it updates automatically. But when the java code writes i, I have to go into the excel file, click on the cell equation and press enter, then it updates

Comment: Excel stores the calculated result of any formulas along with the formulas. POI can write a formula but I think you need Excel to evaluate it at least once.

Comment: So the CSV contains a formula - unusual? `Cell.setFormula(String)`. See the API of [Cell](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html).